# Error when aggregation is turned on in Views

Tags: views, organic-groups

I have a view for Organic Group (og) that displays a list of the groups, a picture, the language, the categories the groups fall into, and a summary of the mission statement. All of this is neatly organized in a grid.

I want to add a membership count for each group in the view. As soon as I turn aggregation on, I get the following error message:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS
>   node_og_field_data_field_group_image_, node_og.title AS node_og_title,
>   node_' at line 1

Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer for this. My view had a group picture; removing the group picture, turning the aggregation on, and putting back the group picture field solved the problem.

It's a problem others have had and that's how they all fixed it; See https://drupal.org/node/1809584.